# Factory Pattern to instantiate classes in a Factory class

Tags: c#, pattern-matching, factory, factory-pattern

I have a Factory class where i instantiate classes based on string matching.

Example Snippet:

```
class Factory
{
     Dictionary test = new Dictionary(string, ICreate);

     public FactoryMethod()
     {
        test.Add("classA",new a());
        test.Add("classB",new b());
        test.Add("classC",new c());
     }

     public ICreate Create(string toMatch)
     {
        return test[toMatch];  
     }
}
```

But now i want to match few number of patterns (file paths) and then instantiate the classes based on the patterns matched.

So my question is where can i store these patterns that i want to match?
Should they be in a "table" in my DB or can i have a hashtable here (which maps to a class to intantiate, when any one of the pattern matches )?

Comment: Rather than hardcoding the instantiation - use Depenency Injection. May be have the Dictionary with Pattern vs Type in the config. That way you can manage/evolve the Factory in future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your `Create` method doesn't actually create anything. It returns an instance that was already created. Every call to `Create` will return the same instance.

If that's what you want, fine, but if you want a new instance each time, may I make a suggestion? Instead of storing an object, store a function that returns a new object:

```
class Factory
{
     Dictionary<string,Func<ICreate>> test = new Dictionary<string,Func<ICreate>>();

     public Factory()
     {
        test.Add( "classA", () => new a() );
        test.Add( "classB", () => new b() );
        test.Add( "classC", () => new c() );
     }

     public ICreate Create(string toMatch)
     {
        var creationFunction = test[toMatch];
        return creationFunction();
     }
}
```

See how that works? The lambda expression `() => new a()` can be called like a function and will instantiate a new `a` with every call.

As for pattern matching, you can do something similar. We put a function in for the value; now let's put one in for the key. Instead of storing a string, we'll store a function that accepts a string and returns a Boolean. Then all we have to do is search for the first dictionary entry where executing the key returns true.

```
class Factory
{
     Dictionary<Func<string,bool>,Func<ICreate>> _map = new Dictionary<Func<string,bool>, Func<ICreate>>();

     public Factory()
     {
        _map.Add
        (
            a => a.Contains("classA"), 
            () => new a()
        );
        _map.Add
        (
            a => a.Contains("classB"), 
            () => new b()
        );
        _map.Add
        (
            a => a.Contains("classC"), 
            () => new c()
        );
     }

     public ICreate Create(string toMatch)
     {
         var func = _map.Where( e => e.Key(toMatch) ).First().Value;
         return func(); 
     }
}


public class Program
{
    static public void Main()
    {
        var f = new Factory();
        var o = f.Create("c:\folder\subfolder\classA");
        Console.WriteLine("You just created an instance of '{0}'.", o.GetType().Name);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
You just created an instance of 'a'.
```

[Code on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5Nulzp)

In this example we did pattern matching with `Contains()`, but since it is Func you can write any expression you want, using any of the string functions, regular expressions, you name it.  You can also mix and match; for example, ,you could use a regular expression to identify a pattern that requires a ClassA, but you could use a regular `==` comparison to identify a pattern for ClassB. Also, we can change the LINQ function from `First` to `Single` if you want to ensure that whatever string was submitted matches one and only one pattern.

Comment: Thank you John. Thanks for the correction suggested and also the lamda expressions.